# Issue Changing Button Text When Request Returns Successfully

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a contact form with a submit button that has three states:

1. Send
2. Sending
3. Sent

Here is the HTML for the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-success': 
 stateText === 'Sent'}" ng-click="submit()">{{stateText}}</button>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
angular.module('contact')
.controller('contactController', function($scope) {

 $scope.data = {
  fullName: undefined,
  email: undefined,
  phone: undefined,
  message: undefined,
 };

 $scope.noEmailProvided = undefined;
 $scope.emailSent = undefined;
 $scope.stateText = 'Send';

 $scope.submit = function() {
   if (!$scope.data.email) {
     $scope.noEmailProvided = true;
     return;
   }

  $scope.stateText = 'Sending';

  emailjs.send("server","contactus", {
   fullName: $scope.data.fullName,
   email: $scope.data.email,
   phone: $scope.data.phone,
   message: $scope.data.message
  })
 .then(function(response) {
  $scope.emailSent = true;
  $scope.stateText = 'Sent';
   console.log("SUCCESS. status=%d, text=%s", response.status, response.text);
 }, function(err) {
   console.log("FAILED. error=", err);
 });
 }
});
```

The initial "Send" state works, the second "Sending" state works but the "Sent" state that I expect to change when the request returns successfully does not. I have set a breakpoint and watch `$scope.stateText` assignment occur successfully but the text does not render on the view.

Comment: did you have any form tag on your html ?

Comment: Try changing this line form  console.log("SUCCESS. status=%d, text=%s", response.status, response.text); to  console.log("SUCCESS. status=%d, text=%s", response.data.status, response.data.text); And are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: @tracyak13 submit button reload the form so when you submit form than it reloads and again set the value "send" so dont specify form tag and define input type="button" rather than submit button itself it will work for you

Comment: @JEMI The button is inside a form tag.

Comment: @Vivz I do get an error in my console when I run the code. The error is: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

Comment: @alfishanaqeel I don't know if I understand the suggestion. Are you saying the issue is that the form reloads when I hit the submit button? The button does not change back to "Send" it just hangs at "sending".

Comment: why you are using form tag? Could u please remove it and try. I think the form submit makes the controller reloads again.

Comment: @tracyak13 JEMI explain well what i wanted to describe you when submit button click than controller reload again and the text value of button again set back to send so remove form tag and specify input type="button" for button markup. Hope it ll help you to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked on the issue with an Angular expert who was able to identify the issue. I am using a third-party service called [emailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/) to send e-mails for me when the button is clicked. This third party does not use Angular's $http service and, therefore, does not trigger a digest cycle when the request returns. By calling $scope.$evalAsync, it forces Angular to add digest cycle to it's queue and therefore update the scope. The functional code looks like this:

```
emailjs.send("smtp_server","contactus", {
  fullName: $scope.data.fullName,
  email: $scope.data.email,
  phone: $scope.data.phone,
  message: $scope.data.message
})
.then(function(response) {
  $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
    $scope.emailSent = true;
    $scope.stateText = 'Sent';
  });

   console.log("SUCCESS. status=%d, text=%s", response.status, response.text, $scope.stateText);
}, function(err) {
   console.log("FAILED. error=", err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-success': 
 stateText === 'Sent'}" ng-click="submit()">{{stateText}}</button>
```

As @alfishan-aqeel said in the above comments, `type="submit"` here will cause the page to reload. It doesn't look like your code requires an actual submit to occur since you are using `ng-click` so removing the type attribute should fix this.

Comment: I changed the button type attribute and am still having the same problem. Here is the code: <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{'btn-success': stateText === 'Sent'}" ng-click="submit()">{{stateText}}</button>